# Aligning StackPanel to top-center in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm trying to create an application which is supposed to measure quick reaction performance of it's user. The application starts up in full-screen mode and resizes it's elements accordingly to the screen resolution. The project was strongly inspired by training_aim_csgo2 map.
It's mostly done, but here is the problem:

I put the Label counters inside StackPanel, but outside of Canvas, which prevents the user from clicking on the target if it shows up visually on the StackPanel area (while in fact the target is below it).

[image: Can't click on it here]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="Canvas" Background="#EFECCA">
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Canvas}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Canvas}" MouseLeftButtonDown="DockPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown" TouchDown="DockPanel_TouchDown" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent">
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Width="50"  Height="50" x:Name="button" Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}" TouchDown="button_TouchDown" Click="button_Click" Panel.ZIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Canvas>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label x:Name="counter_SUCCESS" Content="000" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
        <Label x:Name="counter_FAILURE" Content="000...clicks missed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
        <Label x:Name="counter_NUMBER" Content="0 out of 100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Start" Width="{Binding}" Height="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TouchDown="Start_TouchDown" Click="Start_Click" x:Name="Start"/>
</Grid>
```

Could someone help me solve this issue, please?

What I attempted to do so far was to move the StackPanel inside the Canvas and set it's Z-index value to 1 but then it disobeyed HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment settings:

[image: StackPanel ignoring HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment]

I have also tried to drop the whole StackPanel idea and set positions and Z-indexes of the Label counters programmatically, like so:

```
        counter_SUCCESS.Width = rectangleWidth;
        counter_FAILURE.Width = rectangleWidth;
        counter_NUMBER.Width = rectangleWidth;

        counter_SUCCESS.Height = rectangleHeight / 3;
        counter_FAILURE.Height = rectangleHeight / 3;
        counter_NUMBER.Height = rectangleHeight / 3;

        Canvas.SetLeft(counter_SUCCESS, (ActualWidth - counter_SUCCESS.Width) / 2);
        Canvas.SetLeft(counter_FAILURE, (ActualWidth - counter_FAILURE.Width) / 2);
        Canvas.SetLeft(counter_NUMBER, (ActualWidth - counter_NUMBER.Width) / 2);

        Canvas.SetTop(counter_SUCCESS, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(counter_FAILURE, rectangleHeight/3);
        Canvas.SetTop(counter_NUMBER, rectangleHeight/3 + counter_FAILURE.Height);
```

It appeared fine on my screen but on a different one the Labels were overlapping:

[image: Labels overlapping]

Comment: Both answers solved the problem. Thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any input or hit testing on a certain element you should set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to false:

```
<Grid>
<Canvas Name="Canvas" Background="#EFECCA">
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Canvas}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Canvas}" MouseLeftButtonDown="DockPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown" TouchDown="DockPanel_TouchDown" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent">
    </DockPanel>
    <Button Width="50"  Height="50" x:Name="button" Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}" TouchDown="button_TouchDown" Click="button_Click" Panel.ZIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" />
</Canvas>
<StackPanel IsHitTestVisible="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label x:Name="counter_SUCCESS" Content="000" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
    <Label x:Name="counter_FAILURE" Content="000...clicks missed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
    <Label x:Name="counter_NUMBER" Content="0 out of 100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
</StackPanel>
<Button Content="Start" Width="{Binding}" Height="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TouchDown="Start_TouchDown" Click="Start_Click" x:Name="Start"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to re-order your elements.

```
<Grid Background="#EFECCA">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label x:Name="counter_SUCCESS" Content="000" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
        <Label x:Name="counter_FAILURE" Content="000...clicks missed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
        <Label x:Name="counter_NUMBER" Content="0 out of 100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#046380" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Canvas Name="Canvas" Background="Transparent">
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Canvas}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Canvas}" MouseLeftButtonDown="DockPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown" TouchDown="DockPanel_TouchDown" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent">
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Width="50"  Height="50" x:Name="button" Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}" TouchDown="button_TouchDown" Click="button_Click" Panel.ZIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Canvas>

    <Button Content="Start" Width="{Binding}" Height="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TouchDown="Start_TouchDown" Click="Start_Click" x:Name="Start"/>
</Grid>
```

Setting the `Grid` to have the background, then placing the `StackPanel` over that, you can put the `Canvas` on top of everything and set it's `Background` to `Transparent`.